# NHibernate: Generate Custom Primary Key in OnPreInsert

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In my OData service I have to create a custom primary key in the OnPreInsert event handler.

I know I can't use `@event.Id` to assign the key because it doesn't expose the setter property.

I used the reflection to set the value of this property as shown below:

```
public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
{

    if(@event.Entity is MyEnity)
    {            
        var myEntity = @event.Entity as MyEnity;


        string newKey = GetCustomKey(...);

            myEntity.myId = newKey;                
            var property = typeof(AbstractPreDatabaseOperationEvent).GetProperty("Id");
            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(@event,newKey);
            }
        }

        return false;
}
```

During the debug mode I can see that the value of `@event.Id` is initialized properly, however the key saved in the database is not the one I generated in the `OnPreInsert` event handler.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find some way to use the reflection to achieve what I described in my question above. I tried to use reflection because I didn't know about the Generators available in NHibernate (as I am new to NHibernate).

I have a table named *sys_params* which holds the next key values for different tables. My target was to fetch the next key for my table *my_entity*, assign it to the primary key of the new record, increment the next key value in the *sys_params* table and save the new record into the database.

To achieve this first I defined following classes.

```
public class NextIdGenerator : TableGenerator
{
}

public class NextIdGeneratorDef : IGeneratorDef
{
    public string Class
    {
        get { return typeof(NextIdGenerator).AssemblyQualifiedName; }
    }

    public object Params
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public Type DefaultReturnType
    {
        get { return typeof(int); }
    }

    public bool SupportedAsCollectionElementId
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

And then in my mapping class I defined the generator like below:

```
public class MyEnityMap : ClassMapping<MyEnity>
{
    public MyEnityMap()
    {
        Table("my_entity");
        Id(p => p.myId,
           m=>{
               m.Column("my_id");
               m.Generator(new NextIdGeneratorDef(), g =>g.Params( new
               {
                   table = "sys_params",
                   column = "param_nextvalue",
                   where = "table_name = 'my_entity'"
               }));
           });

        .......                   
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone else. Improvements to this solution are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to check this recent Q&A:

- [NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener not saving to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908367/)

The point is, that as described here:

- [NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener & IPreInsertEventListener](http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener)

> ...Here comes the subtlety, however. We cannot just update the entity state. The reason for that is quite simple, **the entity state was extracted from the entity and place in the entity state, any change that we make to the entity state would not be reflected in the entity itself.** That may cause the database row and the entity instance to go out of sync, and make cause a whole bunch of really nasty problems that you wouldn’t know where to begin debugging.
>
> **You have to update both** the entity and **the entity state** in these two event listeners (this is not necessarily the case in other listeners, by the way). Here is a simple example of using these event listeners...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. As I mentioned in my post `myId` is defined as primary key, so it is not in the `@event.State` array but instead in its own `@event.Id` property. So calling the `Set` method will do nothing as the index returned would be -1.

Comment: I see... just wanted to show where is the issue... Entity and State must go together...